# How to get Artist ,Album in Media Player For API LEVEL 2.2

Tags: android

I am new in android. I am working on app based on Media Player.
My issue is how to get the artist , song duration , album etc for the song which is playing.
I have seen the android.media.RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor class but is included from Api 14. If you have any idea Pls suggest

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Study the following

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html

in the second one Audio class contains classes like Album, Artist etc. By using them you can find the album artist etc.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to query [media store](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) and do any kind of modifications to the tables from there.

A complete nice Example:

```
//Some audio may be explicitly marked as not being music
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

String[] projection = {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
};

cursor = this.managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    null,
    null);

private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    songs.add(cursor.getString(0) + "||" + cursor.getString(1) + "||" +   cursor.getString(2) + "||" +   cursor.getString(3) + "||" +  cursor.getString(4) + "||" +  cursor.getString(5));
}
// see http://androidsnippets.com/list-all-music-files
```

Comment: THANKS to reply,But if i am playing the song through streaming

Comment: @Ankit -  `managedQuery` is the method of Activity Class which manged cursor as per activity life cycle.

Comment: i can't get it in a fragment

Comment: @Ankit - Its only for Activity Class. So you can access it in FragmentActivity or in Fragment using `getActivity().managedQuery();`

Comment: Well thanx for the information,but i used mediametadata instead...can you reply one more simple question???its on simple sorting?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java

Comment: my question is why is the code that has been provided there,not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).

Example:

```
myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.raw.yourSoundFile);
retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(this, myUri);
album = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
Toast.makeText(this,album , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Other fields can be found in [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html), such as:

- `METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST`
- `METADATA_KEY_ARTIST`
- `METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR`