# Why does my sorting loop seem to append an element where it shouldn't?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of Strings using `compareTo()`. This is my code:

```
static String Array[] = {" Hello ", " This ", "is ", "Sorting ", "Example"};
String temp;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

   for (int j=0; j<Array.length;j++)
   {
       for (int i=j+1 ; i<Array.length; i++)
       {
           if (Array[i].compareTo(Array[j])<0)
           {
               String temp = Array[j];
               Array[j] = Array[i];
               Array[i] = temp;
           }
       }
       System.out.print(Array[j]);
   }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
Hello  This Example Sorting is
```

I am getting results, but not the results I want to get, which are:

```
Hello This Example Is Sorting
```

How can I adjust my code to sort the string array properly?

Comment: yes i will , infect i m new to java . and was totally stuck with it , had no idea  about such minor issues ..

Comment: A little bit advice I can give you when programming is stay consistent with convention. If you're wrong about one thing, do that one thing wrong everywhere instead of doing it right some places and wrong other places.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Your output is correct. Denote the white characters of  " Hello" and " This" at the beginning.

Another issue is with your methodology. Use the `Arrays.sort()` method:

```
String[] strings = { " Hello ", " This ", "Is ", "Sorting ", "Example" };
Arrays.sort(strings);
```

**Output:**

```
 Hello
 This
Example
Is
Sorting
```

Here the third element of the array "is" should be "Is", otherwise it will come in last after sorting. Because the sort method internally uses the ASCII value to sort elements.

Comment: what if I have class with two field: 1) `text` 2) `code`. and then I created `arraylist`. and I want to sort `arraylist` elements with respect to `text`?

Comment: @Alex please read about implementing Comparable interface in Java.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from the alternative solutions that were posted here (which are correct), no one has actually answered your question by addressing what was wrong with your code.

It seems as though you were trying to implement a [selection sort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Selection_sort) algorithm. I will not go into the details of how sorting works here, but I have included a few links for your reference =)

Your code was syntactically correct, but logically wrong. You were partially sorting your strings *by only comparing each string with the strings that came after it*. Here is a corrected version (I retained as much of your original code to illustrate what was "wrong" with it):

```
static  String Array[]={" Hello " , " This " , "is ", "Sorting ", "Example"};
String  temp;

//Keeps track of the smallest string's index
int  shortestStringIndex; 

public static void main(String[] args)  
{              

 //I reduced the upper bound from Array.length to (Array.length - 1)
 for(int j=0; j < Array.length - 1;j++)
 {
     shortestStringIndex = j;

     for (int i=j+1 ; i<Array.length; i++)
     {
         //We keep track of the index to the smallest string
         if(Array[i].trim().compareTo(Array[shortestStringIndex].trim())<0)
         {
             shortestStringIndex = i;  
         }
     }
     //We only swap with the smallest string
     if(shortestStringIndex != j)
     {
         String temp = Array[j];
         Array[j] = Array[shortestStringIndex]; 
         Array[shortestStringIndex] = temp;
     }
 }
}
```

**Further Reading**

The problem with this approach is that its [asymptotic complexity is **O(n^2)**](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/). In simplified words, it gets very slow as the size of the array grows (approaches infinity). You may want to read about [better ways to sort data](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/), such as [quicksort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort).

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a late reply but maybe it can help someone.

Removing whitespace can be done by using the trim() function.
After that if you want to sort the array with case sensitive manner you can just use:

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray);
```

and for case insensitive manner:

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this line

```
if(Array[i].compareTo(Array[j])<0)
```

use this line

```
if(Array[i].trim().compareTo(Array[j].trim())<0)
```

and you are good to go.  The reason your current code is not working is explained by other users already.  This above replacement is one workaround amongst several that you could apply.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from **Java 8**, you can also use [`parallelSort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-) which is useful if you have arrays containing a lot of elements.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = { "x", "a", "c", "b", "y" };
    Arrays.parallelSort(strings);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));   // [a, b, c, x, y]
}
```

If you want to **ignore the case**, you can use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = { "x", "a", "c", "B", "y" };
    Arrays.parallelSort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));   // [a, B, c, x, y]
}
```

otherwise `B` will be before `a`.

If you want to **ignore the trailing spaces** during the comparison, you can use `trim()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = { "x", "  a", "c ", " b", "y" };
    Arrays.parallelSort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
            return o1.trim().compareTo(o2.trim());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); // [  a,  b, c , x, y]
}
```

**See**:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html
- [Difference between Arrays.sort() and Arrays.parallelSort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328077/difference-between-arrays-sort-and-arrays-parallelsort)
- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java?av=f

Answer (score 4):

`" Hello " , " This " , "is ", "Sorting ", "Example"`

First of all you provided spaces in `" Hello "` and `" This "`, spaces have a lower value than alphabetic characters in Unicode, so it gets printed first. (The rest of the characters were sorted alphabetically).

Now upper case letters have a lower value than lower case letter in Unicode, so "Example" and "Sorting" gets printed, then at last `"is "` which has the highest value.

Answer (score 4):

If you use:

```
if (Array[i].compareToIgnoreCase(Array[j]) < 0)
```

you will get:

```
Example  Hello  is  Sorting  This
```

which I think is the output you were looking for.

Comment: *which I think is the output you were looking for* - Not according to the edit that happened yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, your problem is that you use the method `compareTo() which is case sensitive. That means that the Capital letters are sorted apart from the lower case. The reason is that it translated in Unicode where the capital letters are presented with numbers which are less than the presented number of lower case. Thus you should use `compareToIgnoreCase()` as many also mentioned in previous posts.

This is my full example approach of how you can do it effecively

After you create an object  of the **Comparator** you can pass it in this version of `sort()` which defined in **java.util.Arrays**.

```
static<T>void sort(T[]array,Comparator<?super T>comp)
```

take a close look at **super.** This makes sure that the array which is passed into is combatible with the type of comparator.

The magic part of this way is that you can easily sort the array of strings in **Reverse order** you can easily do by:

```
return strB.compareToIgnoreCase(strA);
```

```
import java.util.Comparator;

    public class IgnoreCaseComp implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
            return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
        }

    }
```

```
  import java.util.Arrays;

    public class IgnoreCaseSort {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String strs[] = {" Hello ", " This ", "is ", "Sorting ", "Example"};
            System.out.print("Initial order: ");

            for (String s : strs) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");

            IgnoreCaseComp icc = new IgnoreCaseComp();

            Arrays.sort(strs, icc);

            System.out.print("Case-insesitive sorted order:  ");
            for (String s : strs) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");

            Arrays.sort(strs);

            System.out.print("Default, case-sensitive sorted order: ");
            for (String s : strs) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }
```

```
 run:
    Initial order:  Hello   This  is  Sorting  Example 

    Case-insesitive sorted order:   Hello   This  Example is  Sorting  

    Default, case-sensitive sorted order:  Hello   This  Example Sorting  is  

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

#### Alternative Choice

The method `compareToIgnoreCase()`, although it works well with many occasions(just like compare string in english),it will wont work well with all **languages and locations**. This automatically makes it an unfit choice for use. To make sure that it will be suppoorted everywhere you should use `compare()` from **java.text.Collator**.

You can find a collator for your location by calling the method `getInstance()`. After that you should set this Collator's strength property. This can be done with the `setStrength()` method together with `Collator.PRIMARY` as parameter. With this alternative choise the *IgnocaseComp* can be written  just like below. This version of code will generate the same output independently of the location

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;

//this comparator uses one Collator to determine 
//the right sort usage with no sensitive type 
//of the 2 given strings
public class IgnoreCaseComp implements Comparator<String> {

    Collator col;

    IgnoreCaseComp() {
        //default locale
        col = Collator.getInstance();

        //this will consider only PRIMARY difference ("a" vs "b")
        col.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
        return col.compare(strA, strB);
    }

}
```