# How can I sort an ArrayList faster?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, arraylist

I'm doing a class project and I need to sort ArrayLists of custom objects based on the values of their int attributes.

I'm currenly using something like this:

```
public static void Sort(ArrayList <MyObject> objectList){

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < list.size()-1; j++){

            if (objectList.get(j).getA() > objectList.get(j+1).getA()){

                Collections.swap(objectList, j, j+1);
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

The program works well if the ArrayList has less than 10^4 elements. But if I try to sort 10^5 elements it takes several minutes, and I need to sort 10^6 elements. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `List::sort` method:

```
objectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getA));
```

As @lexicore has mentioned below, it seems like `getA()` returns a numeric type, in which case if it returns `int` then it's better to use `comparingInt` instead of `comparing` above, if it's `long` use `comparingLong` or if it's a `float`/`double` then use `comparingDouble`  for better performance.

Comment: Most probably `comparingInt`, `comparingLong` or `comparingDouble` since `getA` seems to be some numeric type.

Comment: @lexicore agreed on using those aforementioned methods but I don't know the exact primitive type hence using `comparing`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your implementation is `O(n^2)` which means that as the array grows, the time will expand quadratically.

Without going into a lot of details of using mergesort which is `O(log(n) x n)`, the fastest way is to use Java's built-in solution for sorting.

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Link to [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).  There is also `Collection.sort(list, comparator)` which allows you to provide your own [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Do you want it to be even faster? You can use the [Java's new feature](https://ttux.net/post/java-8-new-features-release-performance-code/) which allows you to sort with multiple cores in parallel. Here is the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). Notice that `Arrays.sort()` and `Arrays.parallelSort()` take an array as the first parameter. You will need to convert a list to an array using `list.toArray()`.

Finally, do note that `List#sort()` was [introduced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) only in Java 8.

Comment: As of JDK-8 `Collections.sort(list);` and `Collection.sort(list, comparator)` internally call `list.sort` as shown in my answer so it's no different solution really. plus before suggesting to use parallel streams or parallel sort I'd say _measure_, _measure_ and _measure_ to see if you'll gain any benefit.

Comment: There is a difference depending on which Java you use. `list.sort()` was introduced in Java 1.8. It will not work on older versions.

Comment: @Aominè `Collections.sort` and `List.sort` are same eggs, side view, indeed. But there's no `List.parallelSort` which is the added value of this answer.

Comment: Also as JDK-8, `list.sort`  internally calls `Arrays.sort()` :)

Comment: @lexicore Right, I like the suggestion although I'd add that one should measure carefully when attempting to use `parallelSort` or the parallel stream API to make sure you're gaining any benefit or losing on performance time.

Comment: @Aominè You're right of course. Unfortunately writing a correct micro-benchmark is quite hard. There are some experiments available which might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328147/303810

Comment: In the context of >>this<< question, the OP merely wants to sort 10^6 elements in a reasonable time.  Any standard O(nlogn) implementation should be good enough to achieve that.  ("As fast as possible" is not necessary ... here.)