# Sort String[] array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<String[]>`.

example element:

```
test,400000,30
```

So the Array list contains this type of String arrays. Lets divide last value by middle value in one array. so it will be like this.

```
30/400000 = 0.000075
```

I need to sort the array list by these values (lastvalue/middlevalue) in ascending order.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of Strings with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java)

Comment: @justin Skiles. This is not a duplicate of that question. that question is about string array sorting and my one is about string[] array list sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
public class StringArrayComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
        double aVal = Double.valueOf (a[2]) / Double.valueOf (a[1]);
        double bVal = Double.valueOf (b[2]) / Double.valueOf (b[1]);

        return Double.compare(aVal, bVal);
    }
}
```

And then use it with [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-):

```
List<String[]> myList = /* some value */;
Collections.sort(myList, new StringArrayComparator());
```

Note:
This implementation assumes valid input - that all the arrays are (at least) three elements long, that the second and third elements are parsable to integers, and that the second element (which we divide by) isn't zero.

Comment: @ mureinik, Integer.compare is has not found error comes. :(

Comment: @GáborBakos yup, you're right - changed to use `Double`s. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @woof I did not understand your comment - but see my latest edit. As Gabor pointed out, this should be done with `Double`s.

Comment: @ mureinik, Sorry I used wrong grammar. In the return statement java says "cannot resolve method compare(double,double)"

Comment: @woof - missed a spot when I addressed Gabor's comment - it should have been a call to `Double.compare` - fixed now.

Comment: Yes. marked as the correct answer. Thank you so much. What can I change If I need to sort in descending order?

Comment: Just reverse the final comparison (`return Double.compare(aVal, bVal);`) and do `return Double.compare(bVal, aVal);`

Comment: @woof Or actually, even better - use `Collections.sort(myList, Collections.reverseOrder(new StringArrayComparator()));`