# Sort the array of string Lexicographically

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array of string in Java. How do I sort it lexicographically? Is there any built-in function in `Collection.sort` or `Arrays.sort`?

For example:

```
0) BANANA
1) ANANA
2) NANA
3) ANA
4) NA
5) A
```

after sorting:

```
5) A
3) ANA
1) ANANA
0) BANANA
4) NA
2) NANA
```

Comment: Why not just check the APIs you list?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] strings = { " Hello ", " This ", "is ", "Sorting ", "Example" };
Arrays.sort(strings);
```

reverse:

```
String[] strings = { " Hello ", " This ", "is ", "Sorting ", "Example" };
Arrays.sort(strings, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Would this be considered plagiarism?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism

Comment: updated, please have a look

Comment: Seems like attribution would be in order; unrelated code is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] a = { "BANANA", "ANANA", "NANA", "ANA", "NA", "A" };
Arrays.sort(a);
```

Comment: Works fine if input size is minimal, go for comparator

Answer (score -2):

You have just to look at the javaDocs API references for how to sort arrays.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html