# Array in Descending Reverse order in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

How to sort these years in Descending Order in Java ? 
Sample input :

> 1 1996 2 2015 3 2000

Expected output :

> ID: 2 (2015)
>   ID: 3 (2000)
>   ID: 1 (1998)

Below is the code I have tried so fare:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayYear {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    int[] year = new int[3];

    // read element into array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      // input value
      arr[i] = in.nextInt(); 
      year[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    // reverse array 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < year.length ; ++j)
    {
      if ( year[i] < year[j])
      {
        int temp = year[i];
        year[i] = year[j];
        year[j] = temp;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      // print array
      System.out.println("ID :" + arr[i] + "(" + year[i] + ")");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would need to sort the array in reverse order before printing it, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of Strings with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java)

Comment: please search for a solution before posting a question

Comment: yes .. ok i'll try . thnk u :)

Comment: You may need to call  `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    int[] year = new int[3];

    // read element into array
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
     // input value
     arr[i] = in.nextInt(); 
     year[i] = in.nextInt();

      // reverse array year[i] in descending order
     for (int j = 0 ; j < year.length ; j++)
      {
        if ( year[i] < year[j] )
        {
        int temp = year[i];
        year[i] = year[j];
        year[j] = temp;
        }
      }                 
    }

      for (int i = arr.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
      {
      // print array
       System.out.println("ID :" + arr[i] + "(" + year[i] + ")");   
      }
   }
}
      //my output :      
      ID :3(2001)
      ID :2(2000)
      ID :1(1988)

      //sample output:
      ID: 2 (2001)
      ID: 3 (2000)
      ID: 1 (1998)
```

Comment: how to make the first array element  hold the second array element ?

Answer (score 1):

Try should work for array reversing

```
for (int i = arr.length; i = 0; i--)
  {
   // print array
   System.out.println("ID :" + arr[i] + "(" + year[i] + ")");
  }
```

Comment: should be "for (int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)"

Comment: Yes @ Eddie... Should have given it a second thought